How to select hired year for all employees at Northwinds, a simple query
Q. For all employees at Northwinds, list the first name and last name concatenated together with a blank space in-between, and the YEAR when they were hired.
`SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname as "Name"

from employees;`

This works to get the concatenation but what to add for the hiring year?
I tried this: -
`SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname as "Name"
    
 date_part('year', hiredate)
 
from employees;`

This didn't work for me.

In Postgres use extract ('year' from hiredate) instead of date_part('year', hiredate). And do not forget the comma that separates the expressions in the SELECT list.

MySQL
--------
SELECT concat(firstname ,' ', lastname) as "Name" FROM employees
where year(date_part) <Year or date_part <hiredate;

PostgreSQL
----------
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS "Name"
FROM employees
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_part) < Year OR date_part < hiredate;

